# Does a nullhomotopic loop always deforms into a point of it?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g:S^1\rightarrow X$ be paths with $g$ constant. At the exercise 3.3 of Rotman's "Introduction to Algebraic Topology" I need to show that 
$$
f\simeq g \ \  \mathrm{rel}\{1\} \Leftrightarrow f\simeq g,
$$
where $1$ is the $\ e^{2\pi i 0}\in S^1 \ $ and $\ "\simeq"\ $ is the homotopic relation. 
The $\ "\Rightarrow"\ $ direction seems to me trivial, the $"\mathrm{rel}\{1\}"$ element adds that,    if $F$ is the homotopy function, then $F(1,t)=f(1)=g(1)$, but the $\ "\Leftarrow " \ $ got me baffled. From the supposition $f$ and $g$ being free homotopic, ultimately, as long as I get it right, the closed loop $f$ has to deform continuously into one of its point that coicides with the constant.

Can you provide some further insight, or some indications in order to help me make progress?

---

Edit: In this particular exercise, $f(1)=g(1)$ is given.

Comment: Try to show that for any based loops $l,g$, if $l$ is homotopic to $g$ then $l$ is homotopic to $g$ conjugated by the loop that the basepoint takes in the homotopy from $l$ to $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f \simeq g$, so there exists a continuous map $H : S^1 \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $H(z,0)=f(z)$ and $H(z,1)=x_0$.

Constructing a homotopy $f \simeq q$ rel $\{1\}$ will require using two quotient maps.

Consider first the quotient map $q : S^1 \times [0,1] \to D^2$ defined by
$$q(x,t) = (1-t) x
$$
This quotient map takes $S^1 \times 1$ to the origin and is otherwise one-to-one. Since $H$ is constant on $S^1 \times 1$, it follows that $H$ factors through this quotient map:
$$H : S^1 \times [0,1] \xrightarrow{q} D^2 \xrightarrow{h} X
$$
with $H = h \circ q$. Also, the restriction $h \mid S^1$ is our original map $f$.

Now we need another quotient map, with the same domain and range $p : S^1 \times [0,1] \to D^2$, but with a different effect:

1. $p(x,0)=x$ for all $x \in S^1$
2. $p(x,1)=p(1,t)=1$ for all $x \in S^1$, $t \in [0,1]$
3. Except for the identifications in 2, $p$ is one-to-one.

Here's a formula for $p$:
$$p(x,t) = (1-t) x + t
$$

The composition $S^1 \times [0,1] \xrightarrow{p} D^2 \xrightarrow{h} X$ is a homotopy which shows that $f \simeq g$ rel $\{1\}$.